# How to specify TypeInformation in readHadoopFile in flink?

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink

I am unable to understand how the type information is specified in Flink while taking input file from Hadoop. I am trying to do this:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<LongWritable,Text>> data =
            env.readHadoopFile(new TextInputFormat(), LongWritable.class, Text.class, args[0], job, );
```

The documentation says it requires type information as the last parameter. But I am unable to understand how I should give it. Can someone help?

Comment: @franklinsijo here is the link to the documentation  

[Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/ExecutionEnvironment.html)

Comment: @franklinsijo it gives multiple definitions, but they all are deprecated. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: You can see the alternative for the deprecated method under the `readHadoopFile` doc

Comment: When I execute this method, I get this error.
  ** " The type returned by the input format could not be automatically determined. Please specify the TypeInformation of the produced type explicitly by using the 'createInput(InputFormat, TypeInformation)' method instead."**
Can you give an example of how to use this method? @franklinsijo

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example how you can use HadoopInputFormat in Flink:

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

final String inputPath = ...
final HadoopInputFormat<LongWritable, Text> hadoopFile = HadoopInputs.readHadoopFile(
        new TextInputFormat(),
        LongWritable.class,
        Text.class,
        inputPath);
DataSet<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> input = env.createInput(hadoopFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Coding as follow:

```
org.apache.flink.api.java.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopInputFormat<LongWritable, Text> hadoopFile = org.apache.flink.hadoopcompatibility.HadoopInputs.readHadoopFile(
            new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat(), // extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat
            org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable.class,
            org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.class,
            inputPath);

    DataSet<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> input = env.createInput(hadoopFile);
```

Besides maven pom needs this dependece:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: refering from [link](http://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hadoop-compatible-flink-read-know-santosh-bakliwal )